# C++ Replace even number of zeros in an array with only two zeros

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

My program should replace the group with an even number of zeros, which go in a row, with two zeros and group with an odd number of zeros replace with only one zero. If the input has no zeroes, it should be left as is. I've written following code to solve this problem.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cout << "Enter an array size:\n";
    cout << "n = ";
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> arr(n);
    vector<int> temp_arr(n);

    cout << "Enter an array:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    for (int i = arr.size() - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
        if (arr[i] == arr[i - 1] && arr[i] == 0){
            temp_arr.push_back(i);
        }
        else if (arr[i] != 0) {
            if (temp_arr.size() % 2 == 1) {
                arr.erase(arr.begin() + i);
                temp_arr.clear();
            }
            else if (temp_arr.size() % 2 == 0){
                arr.erase(arr.begin() + i);
                arr.insert(arr.begin() + i , 0);
                temp_arr.clear();
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Output of the program:\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

But after compilation I've got this:

[image: The whole array was replaced with zeros]

The whole array was replaced with zeros.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Hello, if the input has no zeroes, it should be left as is, am I correct?

Comment: @Lingo Yes, you're correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have altered the structure of your program (inserted a counter `count_zeroes` in place of auxiliary vector `temp_arr`), but this should work as intended:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Enter an array size:\n";
    cout << "n = ";
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> arr(n);
    // temp_arr not used

    cout << "Enter an array:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    int count_zeroes = 0;
    for (int i = arr.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {          // index to i=0 included
        if (arr[i] == 0)
            count_zeroes++;

        if (i == 0 || arr[i] != 0) {              // corner case of arr = all zeroes included
            if (count_zeroes != 1 && count_zeroes % 2 == 1)
                arr.erase(arr.begin()+i+1, arr.begin()+i+count_zeroes);
            else if (count_zeroes != 0 && count_zeroes != 2 && count_zeroes % 2 == 0)
                arr.erase(arr.begin()+i+2, arr.begin()+i+count_zeroes);
            count_zeroes = 0;
        }
    }

    cout << "Output of the program:\n";
    for (vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: @AztekTR if that codebit was useful, please also upvote this answer (upward triangle button next to answer)

Comment: Ops... true! Keep it up then!